# Using vanilla js append, vue.js loses refrence

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Ill simplify the example. Basically i have multiple widgets on one page and i tought it would be a good practice not to copy all the widgets into v-dialog but use the refrence and apenned them into the dialog and back to the grid when needed. The problem is when i append my html into dialog and I try to run this.$refs vue loses track of infinite-loading componente... this.$refs does not contain ref="infinitiveLoading". If some1 can explain and maybe reccommend better practice.. thx

```html
<div>
  <div id="item_containerTest" ref="item_containerTest">
    <span>Hello world</span>
    <infinite-loading
          ref="infinitiveLoading"
          v-show="items.length !== 0 || this.loading"
          @infinite="infiniteHandler"
        >
          <div slot="no-more"></div>
    </infinite-loading>
  </div>
  <v-dialog v-model="scheduleDialog" id="dialog" ref="dialog"> </v-dialog>
</div>
```

//ignore itemID and columnID, i need them so i can append item back to the grid after dialog closes

```
openFullScreenDialog(itemId, columnId, title){
  itemContainer = document.getElementById(`item_container${title}`);
  dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
  dialog.append(itemContainer);
}
```

Comment: Directly manipulating the DOM when you're using a framework like Vue.js or React.js is always asking for trouble. The framework does not know about these operations and it will therefore not behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Lucero said in the comments, you shouldn't manipulate the DOM with the classic javascript API. The breaks the shadow DOM of Vuejs (i.e. a runtime copy of the current DOM state in memory) and thus, its reactivity and components references.

If you have a content that have to be wrapped in different container depending on a prop for example, you can use slots for this :)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="dialog">
      <slot>
    </div>
    <v-dialog v-else v-model="openDialog">
      <slot>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

export default Vue.extends({
  name: 'GridOrDialog',
  props: {
    dialog: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      openDialog: true,
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

This way, you just have to declare the content once, and it will be on a v-dialog if you sets the prop `dialog` to true.

```html
<GridOrDialog dialog="isDialogMode">
  <span>Hello world</span>
  <infinite-loading
     ref="infinitiveLoading"
     v-show="items.length !== 0 || this.loading"
     @infinite="infiniteHandler"
  >
    <div slot="no-more"></div>
  </infinite-loading>
</GridOrDialog>
```